# How do I enter table content (Treeview) into tkinter widgets?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, tkinter

I created a table which by default reads a csv file and displays the columns. The next step for me is now to be able to select one of the rows. This row should be 'copied' to widgets where I should be able to modify it.

My code so far is:

```
class Functions:    
    def select_table_content(self, event):

        lineselection = self.treeview.item(self.treeview.selection())

        file_content = "Note.csv"

        with open(file_content, 'r') as line:
            string = next(itertools.islice(csv.DictReader(line), lineselection-1, None))
            for row in string:
                self.title_entry.insert(0, f'{row["values"][0]}')
                self.author_entry.insert(0, f'{row["values"][1]}')
                self.year_entry.insert(0, f'{row["values"][2]}')
                self.others_entry.insert(0, f'{row["values"][3]}')
                self.note_entry.insert("1.0", f'{row["values"][4]}')
```

The content of 'lineselection' is:

`{'text': '', 'image': '', 'values': ['Seven', 'Spielberg', 1990, 'Thriller'], 'open': 0, 'tags': ''}`

That is why I thought 'row["values"][n]' would solve my question but it did not. 
The error message is:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'dict' and 'int'
```

Update:

```
class Frames(Functions):
    def__init__(self):
        self.title_entry = tk.Entry(title_label)
        self.author_entry = tk.Entry(title_label)
        self.year_entry = tk.Entry(title_label)
        self.others_entry = tk.Entry(title_label)
        self.note_entry = tk.Text(bottom_f)
###Widget.pack()
        self.title_entry.pack(side="left", fill="x", expand=True)
        self.author_entry.pack(side="left", fill="x", expand=True)
        self.year_entry.pack(side="left", fill="x", expand=True)
        self.others_entry.pack(side="left", fill="x", expand=True)
        self.note_entry.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True
```

This are the widgets were the content should be place eventually.

As always, thank you very much for your support!

Best regards,

Alex

Comment: The error says you are trying to subtract an integer from a dictionary.

Comment: Can you add more context to the question.

Comment: I have added the widgets, the function is referring to. I assume the issue here is the "year" column. So I wanted to import the 'string' variable with a str()-function but it did not work either.